# Delete [Ahavat-Hageir]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Do we really need the [ahavat-hageir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ahavat-hageir) tag? There's exactly one question in it. Should we delete the tag and let [love](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/love) suffice?

Comment: I think tags that don't garner 2 questions in a certain time period are automatically culled from the system. So don't worry about this too much.

Comment: @DoubleAA so long as they don't have wikis.  (A wiki protects a singleton tag.)  This one didn't have a wiki so would have died in (I think) 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the single usage of that tag with the already-existing [gerut-conversion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerut-conversion).